# Algorithm to find a set of "k" marked vertices in a binary tree that minimizes distance to marked ancestors for all nodes

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

This is the original problem I have:

[image]

I need to design an algorithm as described above.
I am not sure how to go about this.
I know that the root node should always be marked because otherwise the cost would be infinite.
I think I should probably use dynamic programming somehow.
I am not sure how to break the problem up into sub-problems.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual problem as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: I have implemented my answer in Python. If my answer is not clear enough, I can add the implementation too.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2: I think your answer makes sense, I'm still working through the details to make sure I understand though. Seeing your Python implementation would also be helpful for me to learn.

Comment: @Pang: I will use text next time, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dynamic state with three variables as follows

```
func( index of node(ind),
      how many nodes can be colored in this subtree(k),
      distance to closest marked ancestor(d) )
```

Now for each state you can calculate the best result like this:

```
if node is leaf
    if k>0 // if we can mark this node the distance will be 0
        return 0
    return d
result = infinity

// if this node is not marked yet, and we can mark it, mark it
if d != 0 and k > 0 
    result = min(result, func(ind, k-1, 0)
for t=0 to k
    // dedicate t mark nodes to left child and k-t mark nodes to right child
    result = min(result, func(index of left_child, t, d+1) + 
                         func(index of right_child, k-t, d+1) +
                         d )
return result // sum of the distances of this node and its descendants to the closest marked node
```

Calling

```
func(0, // root index
     k,
     infinity)
```

will give you the best result.

You can save the result of each state in a memoized table to transform this solution to a dynamic approach.

Comment: Why in the first line of your pseudo-code do you check whether the node is a leaf? We would never want to mark a leaf node, correct?

Comment: "mark" or color. So the first part of your pseudo-code is basically saying that once we've reached the base case (leaf node), if we have left over k marks, mark the leaf node so that its distance is 0, otherwise return its distance.

Comment: Oh. Why never? As it is stated in the code there are some cases where we can mark them. Like when N=3 and K=2. There are many cases when we should mark some of the leaves.

Comment: I understand now that I thought through that some more. I wouldn't mind seeing your python code if you don't mind sharing that.

Comment: @flapdoodle here is the implementation: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23248079/ , I will add the implementation with a detailed explanation later.